# Deleting All the comments in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I working on some learning of my own and the Udemy course I am taking is helping me out to learn VBA so I can create some Macros at my job that will make me look professional. So to the point, the first exercise is asking me to record a macro that deletes all comments from the workbook. I thought I could get a head of the class by using some loops but I keep getting errors thinking I am smart. I keep getting on the cm loop that object deosn't support this property or method. Run time error 438 I don't understand why that is considering when I do cm. it opens the drop down list.

```
Sub delete_Comments()
' just trying to see if the cm loop works because it counted properly with the ws loop
Dim counter As Integer
' so i can use to run through the work sheets
Dim ws As Worksheet
'so I can run through the activesheet
Dim cm As Comment
counter = 0

'loop through the sheets in the workbook
 For Each ws In Worksheets
 'loop through the comments on active worksheet
  For Each cm In ActiveSheet
    cm.Delete

    counter = counter + 1
  Next cm
    MsgBox counter
 Next ws

 End Sub
```

updated loop thanks @JohnColeman

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
 'clear comments
     Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments).Select
    Selection.ClearComments
    counter = counter + 1
 Next ws
```

Comment: @JohnColeman I see that in the goto special now, but it is notes not comments that was one thing that confused me. Another problem I am running into is checking to see if the whole section haves comments because there are sheets that have blank between two rows so if I use an if statement that will mess me up

Comment: Worksheets are not collections of comments, so your loop doesn't make sense. But, worksheets do have a [comments collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.comments)

Comment: @JohnColeman I don't know what happened to your first comment but I figured out what you was saying so Updated my loop to make more sense thank you so much and it work I will post it here

Comment: I was trying to figure out how come I get it to work then I get an error 1004 no cells selected and i used the on error resume next. Basically if I am going through every worksheet to do this it will give an error if no cells were found, and when I use the on error no resume next it does not go to the next worksheet?

Comment: @JohnColeman does that mean my selection statement is wrong because it selected it from one sheet and is looking for those selected cells in the next sheet?

Comment: `For Each ws In Worksheets: ws.Cells.ClearComments: Next Ws`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to delete old-style comments:

```
Sub jkdfsh()
    Dim c As Comment, w As Worksheet

    For Each w In Sheets
        k = w.Comments.Count
        If k = 0 Then
            MsgBox "no comments n sheet " & w.Name
        Else
            For Each c In w.Comments
                c.Delete
            Next c
        End If
    Next w
End Sub
```